# raise a complex number to any power in c language

Tags: c, numbers

People, can anybody tell me why this is giving me the wrong answer??
It should give me -3.00 +4.00i but it is giving me 1.00 +0.00i.
I tried 2 + 0.00i and it did a good job and returned the 4.00 but it doesn't seem to raise the coefficient of i to the second power... Any help please!!!
By the way this is in c language

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
double complex z1 = 1+ 2*I;
double complex FZ1 = pow(z1, 2);
printf("%.2f +%.2fi \n", creal(FZ1), cimag(FZ1));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you want the [`cpow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/cpow) function instead.

Comment: What about abs(z1)... in case z1 = -1 -2i for instance I mean the regular absolute value didn't work and cabs(z1) gave me something weird

Answer (score 4):

Use cpow function. pow is not for complex numbers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
double complex z1 = 1+ 2*I;
double complex FZ1 = cpow(z1, 2);
printf("%.2f +%.2fi \n", creal(FZ1), cimag(FZ1));
return 0;
}
```